# Autogenerate WordPress Post Title to be +1 than last

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm setting up a invoice software in WordPress using CPT and ACF. The issue I'm running into is that I need the post title to be +1 more than the last. For example when a user creates a new post, it auto generates the title "Invoice #10001", then after that #10002 and so on and so fourth.

I've got the code to auto-generate the "Invoice #" portion of the title successfully, just not sure how to map out looking at the previous post, then adding 1 to it?

```
function zozson_filter_post_title( $data, $postarr, $unsanitized_postarr, $update){

   //Then if it is the post type sho7nat
   if( $data['post_type'] !== 'invoices' ){
       return $data;
    }

    //If there is already a titled saved ($update returns true always)
   if( $data['post_title'] !== '' ){
       return $data;
    }

    //Let's build our title
    $post_title = ' Invoice #';
   
    //What better random number that a unique timestamp?
    $random_number = '10';

    //Add the random number to the post title to save. You can do these in 1 line instead of 3
    $post_title.= $random_number;
   
    
     //We now have a post title with ABC- fixed and a random number, tell WordPress to use it as the post title
     $data['post_title'] = $post_title;

      return $data;

}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'zozson_filter_post_title',50,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most performant approach is to store the latest number in an option (untested):

```php
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', static function ( $data, $postarr, $raw_postarr, $update ) {

    // If post already exists and is being updated, bail.
    if ( $update ) {
        return $data;
    }

    // Limit to `invoices` post type.
    if ( 'invoices' !== $data['post_type'] ) {
        return $data;
    }

    $latest_invoice_number = absint( get_option( 'latest_invoice_number', 10000 ) );

    if ( empty( $latest_invoice_number ) ) {
        $latest_invoice_number = 10000;
    }

    $new_invoice_number = $latest_invoice_number + 1;

    $data['post_title'] = sprintf( 'Invoice #%d', $new_invoice_number );

    return $data;
}, 10, 4 );

// If the invoice was saved, increment `latest_invoice_number` option value.
add_action( 'save_post_invoices', static function ( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    // If post already exists and is being updated, bail.
    if ( $update ) {
        return;
    }

    $latest_invoice_number = absint( get_option( 'latest_invoice_number', 10000 ) );

    if ( empty( $latest_invoice_number ) ) {
        $latest_invoice_number = 10000;
    }

    update_option( 'latest_invoice_number', ++$latest_invoice_number );
}, 10, 3 );
```

Depending on how frequently invoices are created, you may experience conflicts (ex: two invoices are published at the same time). A more robust solution is best left to a developer more familiar with your site and needs.